# Is it possible to deploy proxy factory in basechain matching the mainnet proxy factory address?

Tags: gnosis-safe

Was watching the video shared in [loom](https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741) for funds recovery and realised that the proxy address is different in mainnet than in basechain. Making the workaround of the video not possible, since address is not identical.

Was wondering if it's possible for anyone to deploy the proxy factory address at the same address as on mainnet following some steps that you guys are aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to help you the best, we will need to know the address of the factory address. There are then two posssibilities:

- this factory has been deployed by a member of our team, in which case we will have to deploy them on our side;
- it has been deployed by a singleton factory, in which case you will be able to deploy it yourself.

According to your answer, we'll be able to act accordingly.

Thanks!